# Is it possible to link a C++ UWP application to a Mysql database?

Tags: c++, mysql, uwp

Can someone point me in the right direction? I a simple way to connect my database I created on WAMPs phpmyadmin to my UWP C++ application.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no a simple way to connect your MySQL database in a C++ UWP app. If you work in .net using C# or VB Languages, you can install the [MySql.Data](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/) Nuget package to connect the MySQL database.

You can see this similar thread for more details: [How do I add Mysql.data.dll into uwp with c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44643438/how-do-i-add-mysql-data-dll-into-uwp-with-c)